# Java9でのjavax.xml.ws.Serviceクラスの利用について

Tags: java

Java9でアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、
Linux環境でコマンドでコンパイルを行う際に下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

---

```
/var/java/jdk-9.0.1/src/Test.java:6: error: cannot access Service
        ApiService port = api.getApiServicePort();

  class file for javax.xml.ws.Service not found
warning: unknown enum constant XmlAccessType.FIELD
  reason: class file for javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType not found
1 error
1 warning
```

---

Windows環境のEclipseで実行した際にはエラーが出なかったので
原因が分からないでいます。

お手数ですが、ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [ヌーラボのアカウント基盤を Java 9 にマイグレーションして起きた問題と解決法 | ヌーラボ](https://nulab-inc.com/ja/blog/nulab/java9-migration/)

の「Java SE の EE モジュール (java.se.ee) がデフォルトで実行できなくなった」で書かれている事象と同じかと思われます。

[`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-AEF06674-4D9F-4BCF-90EC-F3FBA615F57A)(及び実行時には[`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__GUID-688B46ED-0337-4066-B40C-499731FE7F4B))コマンド引数に `--add-modules java.xml.ws` を付与することで問題は回避できるでしょう。

オフィシャルのマイグレーションガイドの該当記述はこちらになります:

- [Modules Shared with Java EE Not Resolved by Default - Java Platform, Standard Edition Oracle JDK 9 Migration Guide, Release 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3)

---

[`javax.xml.ws.Service`のJavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/9/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html)を参照するとこのクラスは`java.xml.ws`モジュールに属していることがわかると思います。
このモジュールは、JavaEE向けであるとして、JDKからは削除されることになりました。
Java9ではまだ削除されておらず、デフォルトでは参照できなくなっているだけなので、必要があれば(明示的に指定することで)利用可能です。

[JEP 261: Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261):

> Modules that define Java EE APIs, or APIs primarily of interest to Java EE applications, have been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. They are not resolved by default for code on the class path:
>
> The default set of root modules for the unnamed module is based upon the java.se module rather than the java.se.ee module. Thus, by default, code in the unnamed module will not have access to APIs in the following modules:
>
> java.activation
>   java.corba
>   java.transaction
>   java.xml.bind
>   **java.xml.ws**
>   java.xml.ws.annotation
>
> (中略)
>
> These modules are still part of JDK 9. Code on the class path can be granted access to one or more of these modules, as needed, via the --add-modules option.

---

ちなみにOracle JDK 9.0.1では次のようなエラーメッセージとなるようでした:

> パッケージjavax.xml.wsは表示不可です
>   (パッケージjavax.xml.wsはモジュールjava.xml.wsで宣言されていますが、モジュール・グラフにありません)